# Use GitHub libraries on Google App Script - Can´t access

Tags: github, google-apps-script, shared-libraries, eval

I want to connect some libraries from GitHub to my project on Google App Script. But I have no solution for that.

I´m trying the function below =>

```
function GH_libraries() {
 var url = 'https://github.com/WilliamBelini/rshk-jsifenlib.git'
 options = {
   'token'= "yourtokenhere"
 }
 let access = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText()
 eval(access)
}
```

But it generate the error =>
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I want the form to access the GH libraries with App Script.